# Dual of quadratic program with linear objective

Tags: constraint-programming, convex-optimization

Let $c$ and $k$ be element-wise positive $n\times 1$ vectors and let $A$ be a element-wise positive and positive-definite matrix. Consider the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}&\quad c^\top p\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad p^\top Ap-k^\top p \leq 0 \\
&\quad0\leq p \leq 1
\end{align}
What is the dual program of this optimization problem? I am interested only in the dual program due to theoretical motivations.

Answer (score 2):

Your primal problem is equivalent to

$$
-\min_{p \in \mathbb{R}^n}\;\; - c^\top p \quad \text{s.t.} \quad p^\top A p - k^\top p \leq 0,\; p-1 \leq 0,\; -p \leq 0
$$

Then, the lagrangian function $L : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ reads

$$
\begin{align*}
L(p, \lambda, \mu, \tau) &= -c^\top p + \lambda (p^\top A p - k^\top p) + \mu^\top (p - \mathbf{1})-\tau^\top p \\
&= p^\top \lambda A p - (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau)^\top p - \mu^\top \mathbf{1}
%
\end{align*}
$$

Next, we need $\inf_{p \in \mathbb{R}^n} L(p, \lambda, \mu, \tau)$. Since $L$ is quadratic and convex in $p$, the first order necessary condition
$$
\nabla_p L = 2\lambda A p - (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau) = 0
$$

is sufficient. Hence, since $\lambda \geq 0$, we have
$$
\tilde{p} = \frac12 (\lambda A)^{\dagger} (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau),
$$
where $(\lambda A)^{\dagger}$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $\lambda A$. Note that because $A$ is symmetric and positive definite we have $(\lambda A)^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{\lambda} A^{-1}$ for $\lambda > 0$. Consequently,

$$
\begin{align*}
\inf_{p \in \mathbb{R}^n} L(p, \lambda, \mu, \tau) 
&= L(\tilde{p}, \lambda, \mu, \tau) \\ %
&= \tilde{p}^\top \lambda A \tilde{p} - (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau)^\top \tilde{p} - \mu^\top \mathbf{1} \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau)^\top (\lambda A)^{\dagger} (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau) - \mathbf{1}^\top \mu,
\end{align*}
$$

where we used $(\lambda A)^{\dagger} (\lambda A) (\lambda A)^{\dagger}  = (\lambda A)^{\dagger}$. Finally, the *lagrangian* dual problem reads

$$
\max_{\lambda, \mu, \tau \geq 0} \quad -\frac{1}{2} (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau)^\top (\lambda A)^{\dagger} (c+\lambda k - \mu + \tau) - \mathbf{1}^\top \mu.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see if my thought process is correct. I think the primal quadratic constraint is active which should follow from complementary slackness $\lambda(p^TAp-k^Tp)=0$ Now, if $\lambda=0$, this will imply $c=\mu-\tau$ from stationarity condition. This will end up causing contradictions for the complementary slackness conditions involving $\mu$ and $\tau$.